# Extracting selections from pdf and export to new image

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, png, selection

Using jQuery/PHP (and possibly plugins), I would like to know if it's possible to:

1. Make rectangular selections in a **PDF** `<object>`
2. Convert these selections to **PNG/JPG** format
3. Save these selections to (separate) files

I realise I could convert the entire PDF to a PNG, but I'd rather have users manipulate PDF documents.